# Manipulating individual strings based on characters from an input in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, character

I'm wondering how to manipulate individual characters in a string in PHP. I've searched all over and can't find anything that answers this type of question. I want to take a string that's submitted using an input form that, for example, says "this is a sentence" and then create an output that takes the first character of every word and puts it at the end of that word: "hist si a entences". I'm assuming the first step would to be to take the string and turn it into an array using explode(), but I'm really confused as to how to perform the actual manipulation? Any help here would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into `preg_match` using Regular Expressions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Then you can store your matches into an array and manipulate strings.

```
$string = "this is a sentence";

$regex = '/<insert regex here>/'; // Regex expert edit here please  

preg_match($regex, $string, $matches)
// Uses regex against string and stores matches
// into $matches <-- that is optional but in your case you want to use it for manipulation

var_dump($matches); // Play with results
```

Comment: I should have been more clear about the original string——I want it to be done through an input form, so the function would have to be able to take any combination of words and take the first letter and put it at the end, instead of just replacing the entire word itself? I'll edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: Is this while the user is typing or after the form has been submitted? All you would do is run the regex against the submitted value (e.g. `$_POST['usrInput']`) to get your letters you want to manipulate your string with and go from there...

Comment: Right, I was a bit confused, but I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I know regular expressions should be the way to go, but I just found this interesting, so here goes:

```
    $string = "this is a sentence";
    $stringArray = explode(" ", $string);

    $messedSentence = "";
    foreach($stringArray as $word)
    {
        $word = trim($word);
        $firstChar = substr($word,0,1);
        $lastChar = substr($word,strlen($word)-1,1);
        $restOfWord = substr($word,1,strlen($word)-2);

        if(trim($word)) 
        {
            $messedSentence .= (strlen($word)==1)?$firstChar." ":$lastChar.$restOfWord.$firstChar. " ";
        }
    }

    echo $string ." becomes: ".$messedSentence;
```